# Minimal Solr score for inclusion in results?

Tags: solr

I have created a collection of medical terms, using all default Solr (7.5) settings.  The documents came from CSV files and I used `bin/post` with default settings.

When I submit a silly query I may not get the number of rows I have requested.

`http://host/solr/collection/select?fl=anyLabel,score&q=anyLabel:(astronaut%20%20football%20felafel)&rows=9999&wt=csv`

Is there some score threshold?  In this case, the lowest score is ~ 8.  I've run other less-silly queries that return reasonable results down to scores of 2 or 3.

**Why was this result truncated after a result with a score of 8?  Do I have any control over that?**

`anyLabel,score
football,16.0328
astronaut haemolytic anaemia,15.470738
astronaut hemolytic anemia,15.470738
canadian football,14.440538
american football,14.440538
football field,14.440538
astronaut-bone demineralization syndrome,14.188901
indoor football arena,13.135968
australian rules football,13.135968
canadian football - sport,13.135968
american football - sport,13.135968
aussie rules football,13.135968
indoor football court,13.135968
astronaut-bone demineralization syndrome (disorder),13.103226
australian rules football ground,12.04758
indoor football arena (environment),12.04758
indoor american football arena,12.04758
american or canadian football,12.04758
american or canadian football field,11.12575
accidentally kicked during football game,11.12575
australian rules football ground (environment),11.12575
canadian football - sport (qualifier value),11.12575
american or canadian football - sport,11.12575
american football - sport (qualifier value),11.12575
australian rules football (qualifier value),11.12575
"american or canadian football\, device",11.12575
accidentally stepped on during football game,10.334962
american or canadian football field (environment),10.334962
accidentally kicked during football game (event),10.334962
american or canadian football - sport (qualifier value),9.649129
"american or canadian football\, device (physical object)",9.649129
accidentally stepped on during football game (event),9.649129
"place of occurrence of accident or poisoning\, football field",8.518538
"place of occurrence of accident or poisoning\, football field (environment)",8.047099`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no minimum score - anything above `0` is considered a match in some way, and is included as long as the `rows` and `start` parameter make sense compared to the `numFound` value in the response.

In general scores are not comparable between requests, and extrapolating scores to mean "a document with half the score of another document is just 50% as relevant" does not make sense either.

The score will also depend on the similarity algorithm used, which can differ between Solr versions. For 7.5 it's a BM25 Similarity.